# the problem is I want to compute all the total price of the of multiple transactions but the program was read the last order in payment

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char product[11][25] = {"none", "Tapsilog", "Longsilog", "Hotsilog", "Tocilog ", "Hamsilog", "Imbosilog","Burger silog", "Pork silog", "Chick silog", "Sisig silog"};
int price[11] = {0, 55, 20, 20, 20, 20, 25, 25, 65, 55, 75};
int i;
int productName,quantity;
int total;
int user();
void menu();
int Orders();
void payment();

int main(){
    //printf("\t====TAPSILOGAN NI LOLA====\n");
    user();
    int addOrder;
    menu();
    Orders();
    do{
        addOrder=Orders();
    } while (addOrder);
    payment();
}

int user(){ 
    char username[]="admin";
    char password[]="123";
    char input[15];
    
    printf("Username: ");
    scanf("%s",input);
    
    printf("Enter Password: ");
    scanf("%d",input);
    
    if(strcasecmp(input,password)==0)
        puts("Invalid password!");  
    else
        puts("WELCOME");
    return(0);
}

void menu(){
    printf("\t====TAPSILOGAN NI LOLA====\n");
    
    printf("Code\tProduct\t\tPrice");
        
    for ( i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        printf("\n%d\t%s\t%d", i, product[i], price[i]);
    }   
}

int Orders(){   
    printf("\n\nEnter Code: ");
    scanf("%d", &productName);
    if(productName==0){
        return 0;
    }else{
        printf("Enter quantity: ");
        scanf("%d", &quantity);
        
        total= quantity * price[productName];
        
        printf("Product: %s\nPrice: P%d", product[productName], price[productName]);
        printf("\nTotal: %d", total);
        
        return 1;
    }
}

void payment(){
    int sum, cash, change;
    
    printf("\nPayment Function");       
    do {
        printf("\nTotal: %d", total);
        printf("\nEnter Cash: ");
        scanf("%d", &cash);
        if (cash < total) {
            printf("\nInsuficient Cash");
        }
    } while (cash < total);
    change = cash - total;
    printf("\nChange: %d", change);
    printf("\nThank you for coming!");
    
}
```

Comment: Please update your post: clarify 1) the problem, 2) the expected behavior, and 3) indicate which part of the code is giving you problems.

Comment: `strcasecmp(input,password)==0` is not the invalid password condtion!

Comment: Actually in that code has don't have a problem because that program has need to have user define function that i create it and i want to compute all of the total of the multiple orders and but in the last part in payment the output that give is the last order that input in the program and i want to get all of the total of the orders can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

In your Orders function, you are resetting the total each time.

Try:

```
total= total + (quantity * price[productName]);
```